# Openvpn режем скорость

Tags: openvpn

Добрый день, подскажите как сделать правильно, есть поднятый сервер openvpn.
Хочу сделать 3 сертификата, и что бы каждый сертификат ограничивал скорость
собственно 1мб 10мб и без ограничения?
Как это можно реализовать?